# boundingRectWithSize not replicating UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

My requirement in a project is that the font size of the `UITextView` should decrease according the content of the `UITextView`. So i am trying to do estimate the size of the text using `boundingRectWithSize`.

The problem is that the font size I get is a bit too big and some part of the text does get clipped.

My Function :

```
 -(BOOL)updateTextViewFontSizeForText:(NSString*)text{

    float fontSize = self.maximumFontSizeInPoints;

    self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];

    CGSize tallerSize ;
    CGSize stringSize ;


    do
    {
        if (fontSize <= self.minimumFontSizeInPoints) // it just won't fit
            return NO;

        fontSize -= 1.0;
        self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        [paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: self.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle };



        tallerSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height-16);// the 16 is given because uitextview adds some offset
        stringSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.contentSize.width,CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:attributes context:nil].size;
    }while(stringSize.height >= tallerSize.height);


    if ([self.onTextChangDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onTextChangDelegate)]) {

        [self.onTextChangDelegate onTextChanged:text];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue when trying to do the same thing.

The issue is how `UITextView` run's its line-breaks compared to boundingRectWithSize. You can read more details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Concepts/CalcTextLayout.html

But you can actually calculate the exact size! There are basically two properties of a `UITextView` that you'll need to take into account in order to get correct size estimates. The first is `textContainer.lineFragmentPadding`, the second is `textContainerInset`.

First, `textContainer.lineFragmentPadding`: You may have noticed that your sizing is generally always off by `10px`, this is because the systems default value is `5px`. When you're calculating your estimated size, you'll need to subtract this value from the size you're checking against and add it back when you have your final value.

Second, `textContainerInset`. This is a `UIEdgeInset` that you'll need to add back to your final calculated value to match the systems.

This is code based on how I solved the issue:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
    CGFloat lineFragmentPaddings = self.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding * 2;
    CGFloat horzPadding = self.textContainerInset.left + self.textContainerInset.right + lineFragmentPaddings;
    CGFloat vertPadding = self.textContainerInset.top + self.textContainerInset.bottom;

    size.width -= horzPadding;
    CGRect boundingRect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
    size = boundingRect.size;
    // I found through debugging that adding 0.25 rounded
    // matches sizeThatFits: identically. Not sure why…
    size.width += horzPadding + 0.25;
    size.height += vertPadding + 0.25;
    size = CGSizeRound(size);

    return size;
}
```

Note, `CGSizeRound` is just a custom function I wrote that rounds the `width` and `height` of the `CGSize` to the nearest `0.5`.

For comparison, if you create a second `UITextView`, and make sure the `textContainer.lineFragmentPadding` and `textContainerInset` are the same, you should see the values almost identical to the nearest `0.5`.

And to your question about calculating a proper pointSize, this is some pseudo code for that:

```
CGFloat pointSize = 64;
CGFloat minPointSize = 32;
CGFloat decrementor = 4;
CGFloat padding = self.textContainerInset.left + self.textContainerInset.right + lineFragmentPaddings;
CGFloat actualWidth = self.maxTextViewSize.width - padding * 2;
CGRect boundingRect = CGRectZero;
BOOL isValidPointSize = NO;
do {
    if (pointSize < minPointSize) {
        pointSize = minPointSize;
        boundingRect.size.height = self.maxTextViewSize.height;
        isValidPointSize = YES;
    } else {
        NSDictionary *defaultAttributes = [self.customTextStorage defaultAttributesForPointSize:pointSize];
        NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:defaultAttributes];

        boundingRect = [attrString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(actualWidth, 1024) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
        // is the height to big?
        if (boundingRect.size.height > self.maxTextViewSize.height) {
            // reduce the point size for next iteration of loop
            pointSize -= decrementor;
        }
        // passes height test
        else {
            isValidPointSize = YES;
        }
    }
} while (!isValidPointSize);

return pointSize;
```

Again, the above is pseudo code based on my implementation (not meant for just drop in replacement for what you have). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
UITextView *textViewObj;//initialise textview.  

textViewObj.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
textViewObj.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really working in swift,get original height of textview..  try this 
let

```
size = cellQueue.contentLbl.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(cellQueue.contentLbl.frame.size.width,CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))) cellQueue.heightConstraintContentLbl.constant = size.height
```