# UITextView top of text on first line clipped cut

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with a strange issue. When I type in emojis, the top of the emojis are clipped on the first line. It's not a problem with the scroll and I have tried putting the content inset so the text is deep inside the text view frame, but the problem persists.
Any ideas why this is happening?

THERE IS NO CODE FOR THIS. IT IS SIMPLY A UITEXTVIEW IN INTERFACE BUILDER.
NO CONNECTING IBOUTLETS OR ANYTHING. ATTACHED IS THE INSPECTOR IMAGE

[image]

Comment: You need to show your code or no-one can help you.

Comment: There is no code see above

Comment: Do you have constraints warnings on your storyboard?

Comment: No. But I just changed the font now and it works!. It seems that the problem was the Avnir-Roman font. It cuts emoji's in the first line. I've never seen such a thing occur before.

Comment: what could be the reason for this, I faced the similar problem.....

Comment: I think you should put bounty on this question.

Comment: For me this answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826943/nsattributedstring-reporting-incorrect-sizes-for-uitextview-sizethatfits-and-bou.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when using a custom font. I was able to solve it by setting the LineHeightMultiple in the ParagraphStyle to 1.2, but you'll probably need to play around with different values depending on your font.

Comment: This works for me, I'm using custom font Arial Rounded MT Pro Cyr. Why nobody liked this answer before?!

Answer (score 0):

Set top edge inset in UItextview this might help you

> UIEdgeInsets UIEdgeInsetsMake (    CGFloat top,    CGFloat left,
>   CGFloat bottom,    CGFloat right );

```
[YOUR_TEXTVIEW  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Tried that but didn't help

Comment: can u share your code of screenshot what exactly is happening ?

Comment: Can confirm that setting the contentInset didn't work

Comment: I confirm that it works for iOS 10, 12 and 13. I just set textContainerInset.top equal to 3 and emoji stopped to be cut. However for iOS 10 it doesn't display all emoji. Some emojis are replaced by ? character. In newer versions of iOS it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found that this problem happen with **some custom fonts**. For example I was using "Myriad Pro" and the emojis were cut, I just changed it to a different custom font (Museo Sans) and the problem was solved.

Comment: This is not a solution. Specific font may be required very often by customers because it may be brand font.